# Structural-type casting does not work with String?

Tags: scala

Given these definitions:

```
type HasMkString = { def mkString(sep:String):String }
val name = "John"
val names = List("Peter", "Gabriel")
```

And given these facts:

```
name.mkString("-") // => "J-o-h-n"

name.isInstanceOf[HasMkString] // => true
names.isInstanceOf[HasMkString] // => true
```

While this works:

```
names.asInstanceOf[HasMkString].mkString("-")
// => Peter-Gabriel
```

This does not work:

```
name.asInstanceOf[HasMkString].mkString("-")

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.String.mkString(java.lang.String)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1624)
at .reflMethod$Method1(<console>:10)
at .<init>(<console>:10)
at .<clinit>(<console>:10)
at .<init>(<console>:7)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at $print(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
```

Why is that? 
Is it because String is a Java class? 
Can I work around this problem?
Is this a bug/shortcoming in the Scala implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `String` is a Java class and doesn't have the `mkString` method without a little help.

It is a limitation of running in the JVM and using it's native `String` class for speed and compatibility with Java code.

The `mkString` is added to the `String` on demand, using an implicit conversion to the `StringOps`. When you cast the `name` into `HasMkString` the String->StringOps implicit conversion no longer apply and so you lose all the extra methods.

The workaround would be either to replace

```
def f (name: HasMkString) = name.mkString ("-")
```

with

```
def f (name: HasMkString) =
  if (name.isInstanceOf[String]) name.asInstanceOf[String].mkString ("-")
  else name.mkString ("-")
```

or not to throw away the type information by explicitly casting to a structural type, e.g

```
def f (name: HasMkString) = name.mkString ("-")
f ("John")  // Ok. Scala is smart enough to wrap the String here.
f ("John".asInstanceOf[HasMkString])  // Error. String type is hidden.
```

or better yet avoid the structural typing because it might use reflection and result in a slower code.

Comment: Thanks! That explains it. Normally I wouldn't be doing something like this. I was just trying to translate a piece of Ruby code starting with what would be the nearest equivalent possible, before refining to more idiomatic Scala.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @artemgr answer, notice that it's the `asInstanceOf` that is not triggering the implicit conversion:

```
scala> type HasMkString = { def mkString(sep:String):String }
defined type alias HasMkString

scala> def f (name: HasMkString) = name.mkString ("-")
f: (name: HasMkString)String

scala> f("AAA")
res0: String = A-A-A
```